# How to return a function type dependent on a template argument?

Tags: lambda, c++11, function-object

I would like to return a `std::function` whose type is dependent on the type of one template argument of my function template.

```
// Return a function object whose type is directly dependent on F
template<typename F, typename Arg1, typename Arg2>
auto make_f2_call(Arg1&& arg1, Arg2&& arg2)
    -> std::function<--what-goes-here?-->
{
    return [arg1, arg2](F f) { return f(arg1, arg2); };
}

// Usage example, so that it's clearer what the function does:
...
typedef bool (*MyFPtrT)(long id, std::string const& name);
bool testfn1(long id, std::string const& name);
...
auto c2 = make_f2_call<MyFPtrT>(i, n); // std::function<bool(F)>
...
bool result = c2(&testfn1);
```

Logically `--what-goes-here?--` should be the function signature of a function returning the return type of `F` and taking an argument of type `F` but I seem to be unable to tell my compiler (Visual Studio 2010 Express) this intent. (**Take Note:** In the usage example, it would be `std::function<bool(F)>`.)

(Note: I have tried variations of `std::result_of<F>::type` without success.)

Is this possible with C++0x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following compiles for me with both GCC 4.5.3 and MSVC 2010 EE SP1

```
auto make_f2_call(Arg1&& arg1, Arg2&& arg2)
    -> std::function< typename std::result_of<F(Arg1, Arg2)>::type (F)>
{
```